# yaml front matter in a haml file

Tags: html, haml, yaml, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am attempting to use the [haml-jekyll-extension](https://github.com/codegram/haml-jekyll-extension) only I do not understand how to include yaml front matter?  I have the following:

```
---
user: hello
---
!!!
%html
  %title RudyIndustries
  %body
    %h1 Hello World! {{ page.user }}
```

but it ends up getting compiled into the following html:

```
user: hello
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <title>RudyIndustries</title>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World! {{ page.user }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to do I mark the yaml front matter such that it gets compiled into html properly?

Comment: how are you viewing these files?... using a server (like jekyll server) or just opening the html file..?

Comment: @landox sorry forget I posted this after I had figured it out, but it is a jekyll extension if you following the link, you use ejekyll and the extension converts the files when the server is launched.  I think  I may be able to convert it to a standard jekyll plugin though and not have to worry about ejekyll anymore but I figure that out eventually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a back slash:

haml file:

```
\---
user: hello
\---
%html
  %title RudyIndustries
  %body
    %h1 Hello World! {{ page.user }}
```

compiles into the following html:

```
---
user: hello
---
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <title>RudyIndustries</title>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World! {{ page.user }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are two problems with this solution - 1) the front matter is printed in the output file and 2) you can't use nesting with YAML when you escape plain text with backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Haml comments](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#haml-comments--) for front matter. This will let you use nesting in your YAML and it won't reproduce the front matter in your html. The following haml file

```
-#
  ---
  user: hello
  ---
!!!
%html
  %title RudyIndustries
  %body
    %h1 Hello World! {{ page.user }}
```

will generate the following HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <title>RudyIndustries</title>
  <body>
   <h1>Hello World! {{ page.user }}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```