# Using Yaml attributes within Haml files for Middleman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, middleman

I've created a middleman app and am attempting to use Yaml attributes within my Haml files and am having no success. Here's my very simple code:

```
\---
title: This is my title
\---

/ This is my paragraph
%p Hello world! This is = current_article.title
```

However, the above only generates this:

```
--- title: This is my title ---
Hello world! This is = current_article.title
```

I tried the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457920/yaml-front-matter-in-a-haml-file) question but it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I've overlooked or am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In haml you must use `#{}` to display variables, try:

```
\---
title: This is my title
\---

/ This is my paragraph
%p Hello world! This is #{current_article.title}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.